# How to get quartic polynomial function given graph, 4 points, and 1 root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

I'm doing a math assignment right now, which is due in more or less four and a half hours. What I need to find is a polynomial function given this graph [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov4YK.png) and the points on it. Here are the points:

0,15

7,-1

22,-7

26,0

28,14

The other two points marked on the graph were just marked for another question; I'm not exactly sure if they are x intercepts because I can see that they are a few pixels above or below. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: So far, using the point 7,-1 and the x- and y-intercepts, I tried substituting and transposing the terms in the polynomial, so from y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e, I got 2401a + 343b + 49c + 7d + 16 = 0, and I'm stumped from there. I've also tried doing it in factored form, so y = a(x-26)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d), and I don't really know what to do next.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Write out the general form for a quartic function. Using the five points you're given, you should be able to get one of the coefficients right away, and you should be able to set up a system of linear equations for the others. If you can verify whether the other points are roots, or where the other roots are, then there's also a much more elegant way to do it involving the factor theorem.

Comment: How do I set up a system of linear equations? In the edit that I added to the question, I'm stuck with four variables for the coefficients, and I'm not sure how to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

We can set up a general quartic equation like this:

$$ y = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e . $$

We can then set up a system of equations by plugging in each of the points individually:

$$ \begin{cases}
15 = 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d + 1e \\ 
-1 = 7^4a + 7^3b + 7^2c + 7d + e \\
-7 = 22^4a + 22^3b + 22^2c + 22d + e \\
0 = 26^4a + 26^3b + 26^2c + 26d + e \\
14 = 28^4a + 28^3b + 28^2c + 28d + e \\
\end{cases} .$$

This is a system of linear equations with five equations and five unknowns: $a, b, c, d, e$. It's a little different from the systems of equations you might be used to, where you know the equation and not the points - in that case, you have the coefficients but not $x$ and $y$. In this case, you know the points but not the function, so it's the reverse: coefficients are unknown while $x$ and $y$ are known.

If you're familiar with matrices, this is becomes very easy to solve. The system can be rewritten as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\ 
-1 \\
-7 \\
0 \\
14 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
7^4 & 7^3 & 7^2 & 7 & 1 \\
22^4 & 22^3 & 22^2 & 22 & 1 \\
26^4 & 26^3 & 26^2 & 26 & 1 \\
28^4 & 28^3 & 28^2 & 28 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ 
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$\Rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ 
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
7^4 & 7^3 & 7^2 & 7 & 1 \\
22^4 & 22^3 & 22^2 & 22 & 1 \\
26^4 & 26^3 & 26^2 & 26 & 1 \\
28^4 & 28^3 & 28^2 & 28 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} ^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\ 
-1 \\
-7 \\
0 \\
14 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

This gives us the following solution:

$$ y = \frac{87}{69160}x^4 - \frac{31}{455}x^3 + \frac{82807}{69160}x^2 - \frac{268341}{34580}x + 15 $$

Here's the matrix multiplication using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B7%5E4%2C7%5E3%2C7%5E2%2C7%2C1%7D%2C%7B22%5E4%2C22%5E3%2C22%5E2%2C22%2C1%7D%2C%7B26%5E4%2C26%5E3%2C26%5E2%2C26%2C1%7D%2C%7B28%5E4%2C28%5E3%2C28%5E2%2C28%2C1%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29*%7B%7B15%7D%2C%7B-1%7D%2C%7B-7%7D%2C%7B0%7D%2C%7B14%7D%7D).

If you're not familiar with matrices, you'll need to use substitution and elimination, and it'll take forever. But at least the first equation gets you $e=15$, so that's something you can start your substitution with.

Comment: Your derivation of the equation was wonderful but, from the looks of things, it appears that substitution or addition/subtraction would make all of some variables disappear at once. Or, is it for example that $e-4b\implies e=18$ or something?

Comment: I didn't try to do any substitution or elimination, from the looks of things the coefficients don't seem particularly easy to eliminate, but I might be missing something. The first equation is for the point $(0,15)$, so that leads us to $e = 15$ instantly, since that's the $y$-intercept. Then, we can take that value and substitute it into the rest of the equations and eliminate $e$ from all of them, after that I have no idea how easy/hard it would be to solve the remaining equations.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $S=\{x_1,...,x_{n+1} \}$ of $n+1$ distinct values:

For $1\le j\le n+1$ let $S_j=S\setminus \{x_j\}.$

The polynomial $$P_j(x)=\frac {\prod_{s\in S_j}(x-s)}{\prod_{s\in S_j}(x_j-s)}$$ is $1$ when $x=x_j$ and is $0$ when $x_j\ne x\in S.$

Given a sequence $(y_1,...,y_{n+1}),$ the polynomial $$Q(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}y_jP_j(x)$$ satisfies $Q(x_j)=y_j$ for all $j\in \{1,...,n+1\}.$